# Unable to send mail using mail() function in php

Tags: php, email

I am trying to get contact form details through mail. But failed to do so using mail() function. here's my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['rqsubmit'])) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['Field1']);
    $email = trim($_POST['Field2']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['Field3']);
    $msg = strip_tags($_POST['Field4']);
    //echo $name." ".$phone." ".$email." ".$msg;
    $to = 'gowtham@gmail.com';
    //$from = $email;
    $subject = "Software Development";
    $message = "Name:".$name."<br/>Phone".$phone."<br/>Message:".$msg;
    //echo $message;
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";   
//echo $message;    
$headers = "From: xyz@gmail.com". "\r\n".
            'Reply-To: xyz@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();    
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";       
    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n"), $headers);
    if ($ok) {
        echo "<p>Thank you for contacting us!  !!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Mail could not be sent. Sorry!</p>";
    } 
} else { 
    echo "mail not sent";  
}
```

I would like to know where i am going wrong. Any help would b highly appreciated. thank you!

Comment: what is the error generated?

Comment: As a first step, remove the error suppression operator (`@`) from your code and see if it outputs any errors.

Comment: This is the Error: "Mail could not be sent. Sorry! . removed @ too.

Comment: Do you have sendmail or mail server on that server? Is it possible `mail` function to be disabled for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add:
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
to:
    $headers

Comment: And that's because... ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's being rejected due to the lack of a sender email address.

Put your own email address in the `From:` header, and add a `Reply-To:` header containing the sender's address.

Can I just point out that you need to check the form data thoroughly before putting it into an email. For example, I could quite easily send emails all over the place by setting `Field2` to something like `blah@example.com\nBcc: spam1@spam.com, spam2@spam.com, ...`.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, my mistake — you *did* add a `From` header. However, it's quite likely that your mail server is configured to reject emails where the sender address is not on its list of approved senders. That's why you need to put your own address in the `From:` header, and the sender's address in the `Reply-To:` header.

**EDIT 2:**
Also, what on earth are you doing with `$mime_boundary`? As far as I can tell, you're not sending a valid MIME message.

Comment: No issues from Form data. I checked it by echoing. Please check the code i edited. and still unable to send mail.

Comment: Its my mistake. I forgot to update the action="" value in page where form is located. Thank u all for helping me. Finally able to send mail.